# Event Handling with List Boxes and Combo Boxes in Java

Tags: java, swing, number-formatting, numberformatexception

I am having trouble with my applet. I have a text field that shows one item selected at a time either from a listbox or from combobox. When the item is selected it shows its price in the text field. Then, I can choose to press a button, jbtCart, in order to send the item to the cart. I am having issues, whenever I press the button the value is not displaying the value in the subtotal label in the cart.

The error is called:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$5.75"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at LanceSubs$6.actionPerformed(LanceSubs.java:380)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here are the relevant handlers.

```
      //WEST PANEL
  //Select Menu items
  jlstsandwiches.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
      @Override
      public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
          /***int[] indices = jlstsandwiches.getSelectedIndices();

          int i;

          for(i = 0; i < indices.length; i++){

                      jtfItemPrice.setText(sandwichPrices[indices[i]].toString());
          }*/
          int index = jlstsandwiches.getSelectedIndex();
          jtfItemPrice.setText(String.format("$%4.2f", 
                      sandwichPrices[index]));
      }
  });


  jlstdrinks.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
      @Override
      public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
          /***int[] indices = jlstsandwiches.getSelectedIndices();

          int i;

          for(i = 0; i < indices.length; i++){

                      jtfItemPrice.setText(sandwichPrices[indices[i]].toString());
          }*/
          int index = jlstdrinks.getSelectedIndex();
          jtfItemPrice.setText(String.format("$%4.2f", 

                      drinksPrices[index]));
      }
  });

  //NORTH PANEL
  //Select combo box items for special sandwiches and drinks
  jcbospecials.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
        int index = jcbospecials.getSelectedIndex();
        jtfItemPrice.setText(String.format("$%4.2f", 
                    specialSandwichPrices[index]));
    }  
  });

  jcbodrinks.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
        int index = jcbodrinks.getSelectedIndex();
        jtfItemPrice.setText(String.format("$%4.2f",  
                    specialDrinksPrices[index]));
    }  
});

  //CENTER PANEL
  //Display itemPrice and itemSubtotal in Your Subtotal sub-menu
  jbtCart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          double itemPrice = Double.parseDouble(jtfItemPrice.getText());
          double itemSubtotal = itemPrice + itemSubtotal;

          jlblItemPrice2.setText(String.format("$%4.2f", itemPrice));
          jlblSubtotal2.setText(String.format("$%4.2f", itemSubtotal));
      }
  });
```

Another problem I am having in the CENTER panel is, I am not able to add the item prices to the subtotal. When I run this code, I get an error that says that itemSubtotal is not initialized.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: *"Another problem I am having.."*  If you have another question, ask a separate question.  SO is a Q&A Site, rather than a help desk.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're trying to parse a String that contains a currency symbol, `"$"`, and in fact the error is telling you exactly this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
       For input string: "$5.75"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
```

I would instead use a NumberFormat, currency instance instead of your `String.format(...)` bit. It's built to use the current locale's currency symbol and to accept it in when parsing.

```
NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
currencyFormat.setMinimumIntegerDigits(4); // if you want a minimum int digit count

System.out.println(currencyFormat.format(120324.444));
System.out.println(currencyFormat.format(12.40404));
```

---

This also makes no sense:

```
double itemSubtotal = itemPrice + itemSubtotal;
```

You're declaring the variable on that line, so why would you try to have it on the right side of the assignment statement when it doesn't hold any value?

Better would be to declare the itemSubtotal in the method, set it's initial value to 0.0, and then use it, probably in a for loop as you're using it (or with the more compact `+=` operator) if you want to add all the items in some list.

Comment: Thank you very much. I declared itemSubtotal as a class variable and initialized it to 0.0, before calling it in my method. It worked!